# merging a excel file and a text file with similar job

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have an excel file that holds a data like this:

```
Name    Job
Damian  Engineer
Rose    Musician
Eric    Dancer
```

I want to merge this with a textfile with rows with the same job:

```
25, Engineer
26, Dancer
```

So the final out put would be:

```
Name    Job         Age
Damian  Engineer    25
Eric    Dancer      26
```

I have written a something to start but I'm not sure how to have the final output

```
xls = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    excel_dict = xls.astype(str).to_dict('list')
    with open('hello.txt', 'rb') as f1:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f1)
        for row in csv_reader:
            job = row[1]
            if job in excel_dict['Job']:
                excel_dict['Age'] = row[0]
```

Could you please help me on how to achieve the final output above? I am using pandas to read the excel file and csv to read the textfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [1411]: excel_df = pd.read_excel('myexcel.xlsx')

In [1412]: excel_df
Out[1412]: 
       Name       Job
0  Damian    Engineer
1  Rose      Musician
2  Eric        Dancer


In [1415]: txt_df = pd.read_csv('hello.txt', header=None)
In [1418]: txt_df.columns = ['Age', 'Job']

In [1419]: txt_df
Out[1419]: 
   Age        Job
0   25   Engineer
1   26     Dancer

In [1447]: pd.merge(excel_df, txt_df, on='Job')
       Name       Job  Age
0  Damian    Engineer   25
1  Eric        Dancer   26
```

Answer (score 0):

pandas has a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function. This assumes that your csv has headers, if it doesn't you can provide them or use `left_on` and `right_on`

```
xls = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
other_file = pd.read_csv('hello.txt', sep=',')
xls = xls.merge(other_file, on='Job')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. You have to strip the 'Job' column or remove whitespaces from the txt file between columns.

```
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.read_excel('sample2.xlsx')

csv_df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt', header=None)
csv_df.columns = ['Age', 'Job']
csv_df['Job'] = csv_df['Job'].map(str.strip)
xls = xls.merge(csv_df, on='Job')

print(xls)
```